# Using UltratreeView (Infragistics TreeView) control

Tags: treeview, infragistics, ultratree

Hello All
I am using infragsitics tree view control.I have one stored procedure that returns 2 tables 
1.Parent Table
2.Child Table
Currently i m Binding the treeview on the basis of these 2 tables by using loops wherein i take one row of the master table, create one node , find the associated records in child table and add it under the Parent node.
This method works fine when there are few records.
But it really takes a hell lot of time when there are high number of records.

Is there any way to directly assign datasource to treeview ? without traversing through any loops manually? such that we just need to provide 2 tables containing master and child records as the datasource and the treeview manages it automatically and binds the data

Please help.. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this sample http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2010.2/CLR2.0/html/WinTree_Displaying_WinTree_with_Columns_in_Grid_Style.html

You can bind the data to the grid, and as long as you define the parent\child relationship the grid will be able to display master and child records.